# Why is this boolean coming out false even when one of the conditions is true?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

So I have this simple boolean method for checking whether my game has ended. In the main method, I then have a big loop that starts with the statement `while (isGameEnd() == false) {...}`. This loop never seems to break, even when one, two or all of the conditions in the method becomes true. I don't get it.

```
public static boolean isGameEnd() {
        if (lives == 0 || steps == 0 || isMazeCompleted()) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, but none of the conditions is `true`. Also, your posted code is equivalent to `return lives == 0 || steps == 0 || isMazeCompleted();`

Comment: can you show the code within the main method?

Comment: Really shouldn't be commenting on indentation style, so I won't

Comment: `System.out.printf("line: %d steps: %d mazeCompleted: %b %n", line, steps, isMazeCompleted());`

Comment: @Tibrogargan but yet you did ;).

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Apophasis is fun :)

Comment: You really don't need `while (isGameEnd() == false)` because comparing a `boolean` to a `boolean` to obtain a `boolean` is mighty redundant. And superfluous. And repetitive. And redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `static` in the function definition is a red flag to me. If a class is defined with default field values, then those default values will be what is checked rather than the particular implementation of the class:

```
class Game {
  int lives = 3;
  int steps = 10;
  public boolean isMazeCompleted() {
    return false;
  }
  public void doStuff() {
    lives--;
  }
  public static boolean isGameEnd() {
    if (lives == 0 || steps == 0 || isMazeCompleted()) {
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Game a;
  while(!a.isGameEnd()){ // check 'isGameEnd' for the static class
     a.doStuff(); // This does *not* update the static class
  }
}
```

Most Java editors will complain about the use of static functions in a non-static context, so will suggest `Game.isGameEnd()` instead of `a.isGameEnd()`, which makes it a bit more obvious to the programmer where the error is.